# which is the equivalent encrypt/decrypt function of this in php?

Tags: java, php, android, encryption

I have this code in java, i need the equivalent in PHP, i have this code in .NET also and works perfect, but i need in PHP.

```
public static String decrypt(String pValor) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    byte vBytesDecodificados[] = null;

    try {

        KeySpec vClave = new DESKeySpec("MyKey".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKey vClaveSecreta = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(vClave);

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Hex.decodeHex("1234567890ABCDEF".toCharArray()));

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, vClaveSecreta, iv);

        vBytesDecodificados = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(pValor.getBytes()));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return new String(vBytesDecodificados, "UTF-8");
}

public static String encrypt(String pValor) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    byte vBytesCodificados[] = null;

    try {

        KeySpec vClave = new DESKeySpec("MyKey".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKey vClaveSecreta = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(vClave);

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Hex.decodeHex("1234567890ABCDEF".toCharArray()));

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, vClaveSecreta, iv);

        byte[] utf8 = pValor.getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(utf8);
        vBytesCodificados = Base64.encodeBase64(enc);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return new String(vBytesCodificados, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Look at [Mcrypt library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php). Something like [mcrypt-encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)/[mcrypt-decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) should do the job. You may also need [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) to work with binary data.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003.. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @AlexBlex Note that the OP's code specifies `PKCS5Padding` and mcrypt does not support `PKCS5Padding`.

Comment: @seba123neo DES is not secure, it only uses a 56-bit key, it should not be used if at all possible. It has been superseded by AES (Advanced Encryption Standard).

Comment: @zaph I always feel so sorry for you.  You have to repeat yourself on pretty much every single encryption-tagged question and it always seems as if the OP never listens.  Keep it up!

Comment: Yeah, tiring but sometimes productive. That is the difference between SO and real life. My SME friend just says "You can't do that, it's not secure" and that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know it's not safe to use this method, but this is the solution:

```
class Encriptacion {
    private $iv = '1234567890ABCDEF';
    private $key = 'MyKey';

    function encode($str) {
        $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $str = $this->pkcs5Pad($str, $size);
        $aaa = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_DES, $this->key, $str, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $this->hex2bin($this->iv));
        $ret = base64_encode($aaa);
        return $ret;
    }

    function decode($str) {
        $str = base64_decode($str);
        $str = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_DES, $this->key, $str, MCRYPT_DECRYPT, $this->hex2bin($this->iv));
        $str = $this->pkcs5Unpad($str);
        return $str;
    }

    function hex2bin($hexData) {
        $binData = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexData); $i += 2) {
            $binData .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexData, $i, 2)));
        }
        return $binData;
    }

    function pkcs5Pad($text, $blocksize) {
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }

    function pkcs5Unpad($text) {
        $pad = ord($text {strlen($text) - 1});
        if ($pad > strlen($text))
            return false;

        if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad)
            return false;

        return substr($text, 0, - 1 * $pad);
    }
}
```